# delete if a word is not in a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This the code:

```js
const { words } = require("../../json/words.json")

const args = message.content.split(' ')
const wordss = words.filter(m=> m.includes(args))
if(args > 1 || !wordss) {
     message.delete()
} else {
message.react("✅")
}
```

The words in `"../../json/words.json"`:

```js
{
  "words": [
 "apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "earth", "fish", "girl", "house", "ink", "jar", "king", "lock", "moon", "nose", "oat", "pig", "queen", "rope", "shirt", "tea", "umbrella", "vase", "wave", "xylophone", "yolk", "zebra"  
   ]  
 }
```

How do I delete a message if the message is not an existing word? Even if the message doesn't contain any of the words from the list (example if the message was "battle"), the message still isn't deleted and gets reacted with ✅ instead.

Comment: Code doesn't make any sense or incomplete.  Paste your `message` function or class.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention was to exclude all messages that do not contain at least one word from the `words` array then the following might be helpful to you:

```js
const words= [
 "apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "earth", "fish", "girl", "house", "ink", "jar", "king", "lock", "moon", "nose", "oat", "pig", "queen", "rope", "shirt", "tea", "umbrella", "vase", "wave", "xylophone", "yolk", "zebra"  
   ], msgs=["an apple a day","keeps the doctor away","this is bananas","a cat or a dog"];

const res=msgs.filter(msg=>
 msg.split(' ').some(m=>words.includes(m)))

console.log(res);
```